# Iterating over two 2D numpy arrays with index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays of the same shape. Is there a way to iterate through them simultaneously with getting e.g. a pair of elemets from both tables and their index?

For example,
I have two arrays

```py
before = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    dtype=int
)
```

```py
after = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]],
    dtype=int
)
```

I want to get a list of indexes of every `zero` from `before` table that has been transformed to `one` in the `after` table - in this scenario that would be `[(0, 2), (1, 4), (1, 7)]`.

`numpy.ndenumerate` is very close to what I'd like to achieve, but it can iterate through only one array at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass both conditions to `np.logical_and` and then use `np.argwhere` to find indices that meet both conditions:

```
idx = np.argwhere(np.logical_and(before==0, after==1))
```

output:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 4]
 [1 7]]
```